# Node exception display format

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception

In Node.js, when you throw an exception and don't catch it, by default you get a display like:

```
C:\tptp-parser\index.js:19
        throw e
        ^

SyntaxError: Unknown language (33:7)
    at err (C:\tptp-parser\index.js:14:10)
    at Object.parse (C:\tptp-parser\index.js:354:5)
    at read (C:\tptp-parser\tptp-parser.js:14:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\tptp-parser\tptp-parser.js:37:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
```

The first three lines are the location in your source code where the exception was thrown from, then a message, then a stack trace. I know how to customise the message (as in the above example); is there a way to also customise the first three lines?

That is, I'm writing a parser, and it would be ideal if I could change the first three lines to show, not the line of code in the parser, but the line of text in the file being parsed. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

`SyntaxError` is a `nodejs` built-in function.

Calling it from the repl returns:

```
> SyntaxError('here')
SyntaxError: here
  at SyntaxError (native)
  at repl:1:1
  at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:22:35)
  at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:96:12)
  at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:21:12)
  at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:346:29)
  at bound (domain.js:280:14)
  at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
  at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:545:10)
  at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
```

You can do what you need by first replacing node's default `SyntaxError(msg)` with your own. I think you'd need to do this in a required file so it's defined before the nodejs parser attempts to parse your erroring code.

### Update

After a little playing around with `SyntaxError()`, what I suggest above probably won't work.

Since you're writing a parser, you might check out [pegjs](https://pegjs.org/) which allows you to customize errors thrown during parsing.